# Using UPDATE Function To Mass Update Records

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, forum

Due to an incident a few months prior, thousands of author_ids have been deleted from my forum database and I am looking to restore them. Because thousands of posts have no author_id, the original author of the post has been greyed out along with the Guest_ prefix.

[What the forums currently looks like.](http://i.minus.com/i068gx5HnGZvS.PNG)

[What the forums should look like.](http://i.minus.com/if44R39TzsryN.PNG)

Anyway, [here](http://i.minus.com/ibtzcXdX1rEy6.PNG) is an image of the columns the *Posts* table consists of. And here is an image of the [indexes](http://i.minus.com/iBTls0l3Zo2xI.PNG).

My solution:

```
UPDATE posts
SET author_id = 375, author_name = 'Peter'
WHERE author_name = 'petersmileyface'
```

The above was what I had tried, but when I execute the code all the author_ids were changed to 375, thus every post had an author_name of 'Peter'. w3schools states that only if I omit the WHERE clause, all the records will be updated.

Why does my solution not work? Thank you in advanced for your answers.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your SQL, so can only guess that you inadvertently executed without the WHERE clause - it should have controlled the updates as you expected.

Comment: What is the exact error that you are receiving? Could there be a constraint on author_id? If you're manually updating the authors, you could do a UPDATE ... SELECT

Comment: @njk - I actually didn't receive any errors; it all ran fine. I just check author_id and no I don't think there is one, but I could be wrong so I took a screenshot of the 'indexes' (added to question).

Comment: @petersmileyface Can you show us the result of SELECT author_id, author_name FROM posts WHERE author_name = 'petersmileyface'

Comment: @njk - This is the output (http://i.minus.com/ibv5ECtCSpIOFH.PNG) which continues for 134 pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request isn't wrong, you must have missed something during execution.

For mass update, you can use another kind of request, with a CASE statement, try it, maybe you won't have problems anymore...

```
UPDATE posts 
SET 
   author_id = 
      CASE author_name 
         WHEN 'petersmileyface' THEN 375
         WHEN 'portugaltrollface' THEN 412
      END,
   author_name = 
      CASE author_name 
         WHEN 'petersmileyface' THEN 'Peter'
         WHEN 'portugaltrollface' THEN 'Pedro'
      END;
```

Comment: This method partially works. When I used this code this happens (http://i.minus.com/isROd6tdh0h0N.PNG); that is, every author_name and author_id field becomes NULL and 0 respectively.

Comment: I can see Jamie is still alive ! At least we save him... Is every `NULL` is your screen correspond to `author_name = 'petersmileyface'` or your problem happens for other users ?

Comment: the NULL value happens to every single user if I use the above code.